# PeriodicWorkRequest Failed redmi,vivo,oppo

Tags: android, notifications

on set PeriodicWorkRequest, notification not send at every 15 min of interval. Notification get sometime at 15 min, sometime at 16 min, sometime at 20 min, sometime at 30 min, or sometime not shows notification.
I want to play sound every 15 when notification came in selected period like 8am To 8Pm.
I am implemented PeriodicWorkRequest but still some devices not gives on time Notification.

SchedulerActivity

```
    public class SchedulerActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scheduler);
        schedulePeriodicWork();
    }

    void schedulePeriodicWork()
    {
        Constraints constraints= new Constraints.Builder().setRequiresBatteryNotLow(false).build();
       
    PeriodicWorkRequest unused = this.periodicWorkRequest = (PeriodicWorkRequest) newPeriodicWorkRequest.Builde((Class<? extends ListenableWorker>) MyWorker.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTE).setConstraints(constraints).build();

        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("My Work", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, this.periodicWorkRequest);

    }
}
```

WorkerClass

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker
{
   public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
   Context con;

    public MyWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams)
    {
        super(context, workerParams);
        this.con=context;

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork()
    {
        int startHour=AlramUtility.getFromTimeHours(getApplicationContext()); // 8
        int startMinute=AlramUtility.getFromTimeMinute(getApplicationContext()); //00
        int endHour=AlramUtility.getToTimeHours(getApplicationContext());  //20
        int endMinute=AlramUtility.getToTimeMinute(getApplicationContext()); //00

        Calendar calendar= Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar startCalendar= Calendar.getInstance();
        startCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,startHour);
        startCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,startMinute);

        Calendar endCalendar= Calendar.getInstance();
        endCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,endHour);
        endCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,endMinute);

        if (calendar.after(startCalendar) && calendar.before(endCalendar)  calendar.equals(startCalendar) && calendar.before(endCalendar) 
                calendar.after(startCalendar) && calendar.equals(endCalendar))
        {
           
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 1, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class).
                            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            NewMessageNotification.notify(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", "Hello-", 1, contentIntent);
            playAudio();
        }
        return Result.success();
    }

    private void playAudio()
    {
        try
        {
            this.mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.notificationtone);
            if (!this.mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                this.mediaPlayer.start();
                this.mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
                    {
                        MyWorker.this.mediaPlayer.reset();
                        MyWorker.this.mediaPlayer.release();
                        MyWorker.this.mediaPlayer = null;
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with IntentService using handler...

Comment: check instruction from https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because of the battery optimization imposed by these manufacturers.

every time the user leaves your application or the application goes into the background, the phone kills all the services related to your application.

There is no point in continuing to look for it, it's a known problem and hopefully Google will be able to put pressure on them to restore a decent user experience.